# What's wrong in my DOM parser php code?

Tags: php, html, dom, html-parsing

**HTML**

```
$html='<h1>some text<h1>
sometext
<h2>some text</h2>
sometext
<h1>some text<h1>
sometext
<h2>some text</h2>
sometext
<h3>some text</h3>
sometext';
```

I need to wrap `h` tags with `div`. Parent-child relationship is like h1->h2->h3 and so on. So, I need to wrap div according to it

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');

        for ($i = 0; $i < $elements->length; $i++) {            
        $element = $elements->item($i);
        if ($element->tagName == 'h1'){ 
           $wrap1 = $dom->createElement('div');
           $wrap1->setAttribute('class', 'sect1');

            $wrap1->appendChild($element);
            $dom->appendChild($wrap1);
        }
        if ($element->tagName == 'h2'){ 
           $wrap2 = $dom->createElement('div');
           $wrap2->setAttribute('class', 'sect2');

            $wrap2->appendChild($element);
            $wrap1->appendChild($wrap2);
            $dom->appendChild($wrap1);
        }
    }     

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Something is going wrong in my code,When I try to execute it keeps on loading not delivering the output and also I'm not sure whether this code will get my expected output as follows

```
<div class="sect1">
<h1>some text<h1>
sometext
<div class="sect2">
<h2>some text</h2>
sometext
</div>
</div>
<div class="sect1">
<h1>some text<h1>
sometext
<div class="sect2">
<h2>some text</h2>
sometext
<div class="sect3">
<h3>some text</h3>
 sometext
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you done any debugging? What are the results?

Comment: No, I haven't done debugging. I want to know whether this code is correct to get my expected output

Comment: it is not correct, if you want to know exactly that :)

Comment: Ya I want to know that too @Sergei Kovalenko

Comment: you really want not just add a child but convert plain to tree structure. it is more difficult task

Comment: Then what would be the solution for this?

Comment: i cant answer by some words. You need analyse the structure, move below levels  into upper and just after add divs. In common case it is a difficult solution

Comment: Then, As I'm newbie in DOM parser class I don't know how to play around to manipulate nodes to get my expected result so If I do it using regex would it be solved ?

Comment: regex may help if your html always the same structure as in the question. But not in a real case. You should generate right html from the start. Not rewrite it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems lies here:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $elements->length; $i++) { 
------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You are adding new items each time, then the result is an endless loop. You can solve this way:

```
for ($i = 0, $count = $elements->length; $i < $count; $i++) {
```

Comment: Alternatively `$elements->length` could be assigned to a variable outside the loop: `$iNumElements = $elements->length; for($i=0; $i<$iNumElements; $i++) { ... }`

Comment: And one more query, The result is appending at the end of html not replacing the existing html in the place of `h ` tags